# Can't read large text files in C

Tags: c

I'm working on image convolution for a 416 * 416 color image with a 3 * 3 * 3 * 16 kernal weights (where kernal width - 3, kernal height - 3, filter channels - 3, number of filters - 16). I'm trying to do this in C, but first I need to read the image from the text file and store it in the memory before working with the convolution function. But I think it seems that C doesn't allow me to write 416 * 416 * 3 size string values into an array. I'm actually a newbie to C, so I'm trying to figure out what would be the best approach I should obey in this ?
Below you can see the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char line[255];
    int fileSize = 416 * 416 * 3;
    char image[416 * 416 * 3][255];

    FILE *fpointer_1 = fopen("dog_text_image.txt", "r");

    for (int i = 0; i < fileSize; i++)
    {
        fgets(line, 255, fpointer_1);

        strcpy(image[i], line);
    };

    fclose(fpointer_1);

    printf("1st value : %s\n", image[0]);
    printf("2nd value : %s\n", image[1]);
    printf("3rd value : %s\n", image[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you say "I think it seems that C doesn't allow me to write 416 * 416 * 3 size string"? If there are error messages, at compile time or runtime, you should always share the error message.

Comment: The stack is the wrong place for a 132 MB array. Use `malloc()` and store this data on the heap where it belongs.

Comment: When I run the code it doesn't print the values in the array. But when I do it with reading small text files into array like 3 * 3 * 3 * 16 = 432 values into an array. It works fine with printing the values.

Comment: "read the image from the text file" --> What is the file size?

Comment: it's size is 416 * 416 * 3 (519168) lines where each line contain 15 characters.

Comment: @K.vindi Yes, but the `image[][]` array is 85 times larger than that. As I said, this doesn't belong on the stack. Your program is probably failing because of a stack overflow.

Comment: To prevent a runaway stack, most OSes limit the amount of stack space you can use. For linux, this defaults to 8MB. Your array is much larger than that. But, I'm not sure that you want: `char image[416 * 416 * 3][255];` anyway. I'm assuming the image is 8 bits per color (RGB), so that's 3 bytes per pixel. The `255` makes no sense unless it's somehow related to the max color value per pixel. But, that's still not right. Your image array should be: `unsigned char image[416 * 416 * 3]` or `unsigned char image[416 * 416][3]` or `unsigned char image[416][416][3]`

Comment: In fact, I'd define a pixel struct: `typedef struct { u8 red; u8 green; u8 blue } __attribute__((__packed__)) pixel_t;` and do: `pixel_t image[416][416];` but you'll still have to allocate `image` from `malloc` The convolution kernals aren't part of the image array itself. They're how you index into the pixel array to apply a given transform. See my recent answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61623303/c-rgb-values-calculating-the-average-of-rgb-values-for-a-blur-filter/61623934#61623934 for an example of a blur filter

Comment: And, despite the `.txt` extension, you're [probably] reading _binary_ data. You want `fread` and not `fgets`. You didn't describe the file format. If it's _truly_ text data [of which I'm skeptical], you'll need to use `strtol` in your original loop to decode each pixel value.

Comment: if you use malloc instead, you should first also check the size of the file to know exact how many bytes you need to allocate instead of some magic number 416.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alternatively use pointer to array (instead of pointer to pointer) to allocate the entire matrix with a single malloc, and deallocate it with a single free:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    /*Pointer to array of length 255*/
    char (*image)[255];

    /*One malloc to allocate memory*/
    if(!(image = malloc(416 * 416 * 3 * sizeof *image))){
        perror("Bad allocation!");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Do stuff with the matrix*/
    image[400][100] = 'a';


    /*One free to deallocate memory*/
    if(image){
        free(image);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's likely you are getting a stack overflow, try allocating the memory to the heap, something like replacing

```
char image[416 * 416 * 3][255];
```

with

```
//...
char **image;

if(!(image = malloc((fileSize) * sizeof(*image)))){
    perror("Bad allocation!");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

for(int i = 0; i < fileSize; i++) {
    if(!(image[i] = malloc(255))){
        perror("Bad allcation!");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
//...
```

To free the memory it's the other way around:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fileSize; i++){
    if(image[i])
        free(image[i]);
}
if(image)
    free(image);
```

Also, in the code

```
//...
fgets(line, 255, fpointer_1);
strcpy(image[i], line;
//...
```

`strcpy` is really unnecessary you can read directly to `image[i]` in `fgets`.

It's possible you can solve the issue with the help of [@CraigEstey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5382650/craig-estey)'s comments, try that first.