# I'm trying to blur a bitmap by looping through pixels row by row, but the program crashes

Tags: c, winapi

I coded this part to WM_PAINT right after loading a bitmap 30x30 pixels and it looks like this:

The image loads correctly but then the app not responds at all

```
    StretchBlt(hdc, 0, 0, rect.right, rect.bottom, hmem, 0, 0, bmp.bmWidth, bmp.bmHeight, SRCCOPY); 

    for (int i = 150; i < rect.right; i++) { // 0 0 start point
        for (int j = 0; j < rect.bottom; j++) {
            COLORREF center = GetPixel(hdc, i, j);
            int red = GetRValue(center);
            int green = GetGValue(center);
            int blue = GetBValue(center);


            if (i - 1 >= 0 && j - 1 >= 0) {//has pixel at left & top = top left corner
                COLORREF topLeft = GetPixel(hdc, i - 1, j - 1);
                int redTL = GetRValue(topLeft);
                int greenTL = GetGValue(topLeft);
                int blueTL = GetBValue(topLeft);
                red = (red + redTL) / 2;
                green = (green + greenTL) / 2;
                blue = (blue + blueTL) / 2;

            }
            if (i - 1 >= 0) {//has pixel at left
                COLORREF left = GetPixel(hdc, i - 1, j);
                int redL = GetRValue(left);
                int greenL = GetGValue(left);
                int blueL = GetBValue(left);
                red = (red + redL) / 2;
                green = (green + greenL) / 2;
                blue = (blue + blueL) / 2;

            }
            if (i - 1 >= 0 && j + 1 < rect.bottom) {//has pixel at left & bottom = bottom left corner
                COLORREF bottomLeft = GetPixel(hdc, i - 1, j + 1);
                int redBL = GetRValue(bottomLeft);
                int greenBL = GetGValue(bottomLeft);
                int blueBL = GetBValue(bottomLeft);
                red = (red + redBL) / 2;
                green = (green + greenBL) / 2;
                blue = (blue + blueBL) / 2;
            }
            if (j - 1 >= 0) {//has pixel at top
                COLORREF top = GetPixel(hdc, i, j - 1);
                int redT = GetRValue(top);
                int greenT = GetGValue(top);
                int blueT = GetBValue(top);
                red = (red + redT) / 2;
                green = (green + greenT) / 2;
                blue = (blue + blueT) / 2;

            }
            if (j + 1 < rect.bottom) { //has pixel at bottom
                COLORREF bottom = GetPixel(hdc, i, j + 1);
                int redB = GetRValue(bottom);
                int greenB = GetGValue(bottom);
                int blueB = GetBValue(bottom);
                red = (red + redB) / 2;
                green = (green + greenB) / 2;
                blue = (blue + blueB) / 2;

            }
            if (i + 1 < rect.right && j - 1 >= 0) {//has pixel at right & top = upper right corner
                COLORREF topRight = GetPixel(hdc, i + 1, j - 1);
                int redTR = GetRValue(topRight);
                int greenTR = GetGValue(topRight);
                int blueTR = GetBValue(topRight);
                red = (red + redTR) / 2;
                green = (green + greenTR) / 2;
                blue = (blue + blueTR) / 2;
            }
            if (i + 1 < rect.right) { //has pixel at right
                COLORREF right = GetPixel(hdc, i + 1, j);
                int redR = GetRValue(right);
                int greenR = GetGValue(right);
                int blueR = GetBValue(right);
                red = (red + redR) / 2;
                green = (green + greenR) / 2;
                blue = (blue + blueR) / 2;
            }
            if (i + 1 < rect.right && j + 1 < rect.bottom) { //has pixel at right & bottom = bottom right corner
                COLORREF bottomRight = GetPixel(hdc, i + 1, j + 1);
                int redBR = GetRValue(bottomRight);
                int greenBR = GetGValue(bottomRight);
                int blueBR = GetBValue(bottomRight);
                red = (red + redBR) / 2;
                green = (green + greenBR) / 2;
                blue = (blue + blueBR) / 2;
            }
            SetPixel(hdc, i, j, RGB(red, green, blue));

        }
    }

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);         // Release DC
    return 0;
```

I'm looping row-by-row and getting an average RGB color of a current pixel to the ones from neighboring pixels and then setting that current pixel to the new color
Why is it now working?

Comment: `but then the app not responds at all` are you sure it's not just taking a long time? `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` are notoriously slow for bulk work like this - it's better to get the bits into a buffer and work on that (albeit also more complex because you  have to potentially deal with different bitmap formats). Of course, even better would be to use an effect that's supported by the hardware.

Comment: A 30x30 pixel image should not take *so* long, but why are you using `150` in `for (int i = 150; ... `? How is that related to the size of the image?

Comment: Unrelated: You're not computing the average RGB value correctly. As it is, the bottom right pixel will contribute half of the result value, and the starting (center) value very little if anything.

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh I was woking with the bitmap starting from x=150, and i reduced current example  code for help. even if i change it to 0 it is still loads infiniti and nothing happens.
Exactly, it should not load that long that is why i changed the size of a bitmap and still nothing

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I dont mind it woking slow, that is why i went with get&set pixel, but damn it still does not work

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm That's the only thing i came up with after  10 hours..
You have any ideas?

Comment: BTW unsure what you are doing, but you need to create a *new* image so that you do not use pixels values that have already been blurred.

Comment: @all
Guuys, it wooorks and really slow and moves as a tetris snake, i just needed to floor the rgb values since I divide them by 2 and some of them have odd value

Comment: You should sum all the neighbour r,g,b component values, and count how many pixels you summed. Then average them when the sum is complete.

Comment: i just divided by 2 every time i add neighbor pixel.

Comment: Reduce your code to only do a `GetPixel` followed immediately by a `SetPixel` and see if that runs quickly. If yes, then expand with a few steps at a time of your code, until you have found the problem.

Comment: Guys and the codee really works id ont even need to floor I just didnt notice the changes because somhow my 30x30 pixel bitmap expanded to 1500 pixes so as @500-InternalServerError you are right! i just dind'n notice changes because the first ros were of the same color

Comment: I think there are simpler ways to blur. See my answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61395136/5382650 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/61623934/5382650 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/62331838/5382650